# Raspberry Pi 4: upgraded kernel is not selected in the next boot

Tags: upgrade, kernel, raspberrypi

(Cross-posted from [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132676/ubuntu-upgraded-kernel-is-not-selected-in-the-next-boot))

My Raspberry Pi 4 was originally loaded with Ubuntu 21.04, but after yesterday's release of 21.10, I upgraded using the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Among the other upgraded packages, there was a new Linux kernel: prior to the upgrade, the kernel version was `5.11.0-1019-raspi`, while a new version `5.13.0-1008-raspi` was installed in the course of the upgrade.

After the requested reboot at the end of the upgrade process, I found out that kernel version `5.11.0-1019-raspi` was still in use. I have attempted to reinstall modules such as `linux-image-5.13.0-1008-raspi`, `linux-image-raspi` `linux-modules-5.13.0-1008-raspi` and `linux-raspi`, as well as removing the old kernel version. I have confirmed that `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/firmware/vmlinuz` point to the same file, and it is the one for version `5.13.0-1008-raspi`. Furthermore, after removing the old version, even `vmlinuz.old` points to the new version, so I have no idea where the system is fetching the old version from. Note that there have been quite a few reboots in the process, even a physical one by removing the power cable.

Regardless of everything done above, the system still boots to `5.11.0-1019-raspi`. I suspect there's a missing installation step that updates some kind of onboard memory on the Raspberry Pi.

Note that, ever since installing Ubuntu 21.04 in this board a few months ago, I've seen `apt upgrade` install new kernel versions -- I am made aware of this due to the need to recompile a custom kernel module. Thus, the upgrade has worked automatically in the past. I'm not sure why it's not working this time.

My question is: what do I need to do make the Raspberry Pi boot the new version of the kernel?

**EDIT**: as requested, these are the contents of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

As for `grub-editenv`, which didn't even exist (I had to install the `grub-common` `apt` package), its output is empty. I may be wrong, but doesn't Raspberry Pi use its own boot system which sidesteps `grub`?

Comment: Please add `cat /etc/default/grub` to your question. and `grub-editenv list`

Comment: you are right. I missed the raspi part. :( Not enough coffee. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command fixed it:

```
sudo flash-kernel 5.13.0-1008-raspi
```

I'm pretty sure I saw the same output in the course of my attempts described in the question, but anyway, it's fixed now.